# HTML Recording video on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, html, video

I'm new to HTML coding, and i'm currently trying to build an app in iOS like snapchat, that will take a users camera and record without stopping if the user goes into the main menu or whatever. I'm looking for some HTML5 code that will allow me to have the main interface just be the back camera output, with buttons that i'll have over the front.

A few searches have led me here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Which I have tried to make work but iOS does not support it.

I'm basically asking: How do I make an app record video with it starting on screen?

Comment: The amount of hell that you are going to have to go through to make IOS fit into an HTML box is more than the amount of hell that you will have to go through to just learn ObjC like a boss and get this functionality working the right way. There's a billion things that you could do to make this work using ObjC and they work without causing the app to look like it was developed in HTML.

Comment: @larcerax Ok, So objC has the functionality right?, What's the best app builder on PC that uses it?

Comment: Ahh, you got me there, unfortunately, there's no really viable solution for a PC, so yes, you are stuck with a framework unless you get a Mac, so, this is a rough one, I think it's terrible to have to buy a Mac for Objective C. The alternative is to use something like this: TokBox render video, record it, use a web view in the JavaScript or HTML app and then you are set, the problem with this, however, is that you may be rejected from the Iphone store.

Comment: In fact, better yet, if you can't buy a Mac, then use Xamarin, you can use it on a PC, I still don't like Xamarin that much, but it's likely your best alternative and will be the MOST painfree of all non-native IOS solutions

Comment: @Larcerax Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: @Larcerax Xamarin is really nice, but its too damn expensive and the starter edition really doesn't allow you to do much.

Comment: yep, I know, it's going to be a rough journey without going full mac

Answer (score 0):

You *could* write a web app to do this, but not a native app (i.e. from the App Store). For that, you'll need to learn Objective-C or Swift, then take a look at the AVFoundation framework.